# How to find the event triggered before settings event is triggered in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, window-functions

I want to find the event triggered before the event setting was triggered. For instance a user might click on setting from home_screen (home_screen being the event). There might be multiple sources(events) from where the user might tap on setting. How to find out the count of users from different sources?

Events that might help: user_pseudo_id, event_name, event_timestamp(in micros)

event_timestamp and event_name
[image: event_timestamp and event_name]

user_pseudo_id
[image: user_pseudo_id]

Desired Results (Here screen refers to previous source from where the setting was triggered)
[image: Desired Results (Here screen refers to previous source from where the setting was triggered)]

I'm using BigQuery standard SQL.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results in the question *as text tables*.  I removed the irrelevant database tags.

Comment: Added sample dataset image and the desired results.

Comment: I am not exactly clear on what you are trying to do. Usually, if there is a need to join Data with different Sources, then it is recommended to link the Analytics Data to BigQuery, which allows for more complex analysis like querying large data sets and joining multiple data sources. That way, I believe you would be able to query the data sets for the count of users from different sources. Is that what you are suggesting? Also, please explain more about the Title, trying to find the event triggered before settings event is triggered in BigQuery?

Comment: @oakinlaja By different sources I mean the events triggered before an event is triggered. Like say purchase event is triggered after store event (so in this case store would be the source).

Answer (score 1):

You want screen_view from Analytics. "When a screen transition occurs, Analytics logs a screen_view event that identifies the new screen."[1].

You'll be able to access firebase_previous_screen, firebase_previous_class, firebase_previous_id parameters[2]

[1]https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#automatically_track_screens
[2]https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en

Comment: Wow! Thanks! This is helpful, I was wondering the same could be done via querying using window functions. Nonetheless, it's great!